# How to customize flask.ext.security.forms.LoginForm to prompt and use username instead of email?

Tags: flask, flask-security

How to customize flask.ext.security.forms.LoginForm to prompt and use username instead of email?

**I have tried this,**

```
class ExtendedLoginForm(LoginForm):
    name = TextField('User Name:', [Required()])
    del LoginForm.email

security = Security(app, user_datastore, login_form=ExtendedLoginForm)
```

**Changed the template,**

```
<form action="{{ url_for_security('login') }}" method="POST" name="login_user_form">
    {{ login_user_form.hidden_tag() }}
    **{{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.name) }}**
    {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.password) }}
    {{ render_field_with_errors(login_user_form.remember) }}
    {{ render_field(login_user_form.next) }}
    {{ render_field(login_user_form.submit) }}
</form>
```

**changed userdb to use name instead of email**

But still flask-security tries to find email in datastore instead of user.

Answer (score 2):

To **login with a name instead of an email address** (using Flask-Security 1.7.0 or higher), you can replace the `email` field with a `name` field in the `User` model

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

and update the `app` configuration.

```
app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = 'name'
```

Next, to allow users to login using a name instead of an email, we will use the fact that the [LoginForm validation method](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/forms.py) assumes the user identity attribute is in the `email` form field.

```
from flask_security.forms import LoginForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class ExtendedLoginForm(LoginForm):
    email = StringField('Username', [InputRequired()])

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore,
                    login_form=ExtendedLoginForm)
```

This way, we can login using a name without rewriting the validation method or the login template. Of course, this is a hack and the more correct approach would be to add a custom `validate` method (which checks a `name` form field) to the `ExtendedLoginForm` class and to update the login template accordingly (as done by Raja R above). Or even better, to replace the 'email' form field in 'LoginForm' with a 'user_identity' field and rewrite the validate method to accommodate any user identity field.

However, the approach above makes it easy to **login with a name or an email address**. To do this, define a user model with both a name and email field.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, index=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

and update the `app` configuration.

```
app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = ('name','email')
```

Finally, create the custom login form.

```
from flask_security.forms import LoginForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

class ExtendedLoginForm(LoginForm):
    email = StringField('Username or Email Address', [InputRequired()])

# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore,
                    login_form=ExtendedLoginForm)
```

Now, when logging in, Flask-Security will accept an email or name in the email form field.

Comment: Correct, allowing either name or email is very simple. Just set the SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES and either will work.

Answer (score 1):

In earlier versions of flask-security, the unique identifier of the user was the email property. You could extend models by adding your own properties, but the email field still served to uniquely identify the user (so the username had to be the email field). 
From version 1.7.0 it is possible to identify user with a different property.
In the config file you should add the

```
app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = 'name'
```

But you still have to have the email property in your model.
There was a issue reported 3 days on git, for exactly what you are looking for
https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/396

Comment: I tried the same,  but didn't work.  I use flask-security v 1.7.5

Comment: `inline`app.config['SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES'] = 'username'
class User(db.Document, UserMixin):
    username         = db.StringField(required=True, unique=True, index=True)
But I got: "response": {
"errors": {
"email": [1]
0:  "Email not provided"
-
}-
}